# Installing the recent verion

Tags: 18.04

Is it ok to install the recent version of Ubuntu in the core i3 processor.
Is there any issue coming after installing that.
I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think there will be any issues on installing the Ubuntu on a i3 system. If you can probably you can list your system specifications in a little more details for people to provide some more guidance.

Comment: Skype, slack, eclipse and most of the apps are crushing Ubuntu 18.10 desktop

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to [try Ubuntu live without installing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389). When you boot from a USB pendrive or DVD disk, you can run various versions and flavours of Ubuntu live, and after that install the [version and flavour](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) that works best and you like best.

- Versions: 16.04.x LTS, 18.04.1 LTS, 18.10; I would recommend that you start with the newest LTS version, now 18.04.1. LTS is Long Time Support. The version 18.10 is only supported for 9 months (until July 2019), while standard Ubuntu is supported for 5 years, until April 2023.
- Community flavours: Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, ... Xubuntu. The LTS versions of the community flavours are supported for 3 years. The main differences are

  - the desktop environment,
  - the set of program packages that are bundled with the installation.

This means that the footprints are different.

- Standard Ubuntu and Kubuntu have powerful and fancy environments and program packages and need rather new and powerful hardware.
- Lubuntu has an ultra light desktop environment and light program packages, and can be used with old or weak hardware.
- Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu have medium light desktop environments and software and can also be used with old or weak hardware.
- Some people prefer the ultra light or medium light flavours also in powerful computers.

The community flavours are developed and maintained by volunteers, while standard Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server are maintained by the company Canonical.